# VLCJ Pro - Null pointer exception on playMedia

Tags: java, vlcj

I am trying to create a simple media player application using VLCJ pro. I have a need for multiple instances of the media player in the same application, so I have switched from VLCJ to VLCJ pro and am currently using VLCJ Pro trial version 1.2.0. I followed the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024983/vlcj-pro-java-returned-57005). The exact code is pasted below.

```
package com.test.vlcjProTest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.libvlc_media_t;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcjpro.client.player.OutOfProcessMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcjpro.client.player.OutOfProcessMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcjpro.client.player.OutOfProcessMediaPlayerComponentFactory;

public class vlcjpro {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        OutOfProcessMediaPlayerComponentFactory theFactory = new OutOfProcessMediaPlayerComponentFactory();
        OutOfProcessMediaPlayerComponent theComponent = theFactory.newOutOfProcessMediaPlayerComponent();

        Canvas theVideoCanvas = new Canvas();
        theVideoCanvas.setFocusable(true);
        theVideoCanvas.setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
        theVideoCanvas.setLocation(0, 0);

        theComponent.setVideoSurface(theVideoCanvas);

        OutOfProcessMediaPlayer theMediaPlayer = theComponent.mediaPlayer();
//        theMediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.setBackground(Color.black);
        mainFrame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
        mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
        mainFrame.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.add(theVideoCanvas);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        theMediaPlayer.playMedia("rtsp://192.168.178.21:8554/live");

    }
}
```

On executing it, I get a null pointer exception at the line where i playMedia. I have tried using a video file from my local disc as well, with the same outcome. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to say, but there was likely some error during initialisation of the 'remote' media player. You need to enable client and server logs and inspect them, as per the user guide.

Comment: Looks like you are streaming video from the network have a look at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343523/video-streaming-in-vlcj)

Comment: Looks like you are streaming video from the network have a look at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343523/video-streaming-in-vlcj)